# Checking if a POI is on the road

Tags: qgis, shapefile, road, point-of-interest

I have a list of POIs from around the world and their latlongs. I also have the database from all roads in the world. What I want to do is find the **popular** roads from all of these.

My idea was to check how many POIs are there on this road. Hence with the number of POIs and the popularity of these POIs (I have this) i can write a simple arithmetic function to approximate the popularity of the street

My question is: How can I determine that a POI exists on a road.Consider that I have a shapefile for roads and  as a table of POIs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

geocode the points of interest. then take your road centerline shapefile and create a buffer around it that is adequate for your needs (as some points of interest may be 40' off the road, etc)  then do a spatial join of all POIs that fall inside the road buffer.

Comment: There is a short tutorial, about point-in-polygon location in QGIS. als.com/en/docs/points_in_polygon.html

Comment: @dmitry.v.kiselev thanks for the link. Ill give it a go !

Comment: I was able to map all my pois and the road shapefile. Im unable to find the unites for the buffer distance. What are the units ? metres ? kilometres? miles ?

Comment: units are whatever you want the width of the buffer to be in.  Consider a road is usually like 100 feet wide wide and you want your POIs that are right off the road to count so you say they are within 100 feet of the road, then you would want a buffer of 150 feet.  If you want to include POIs that are say 1/4 mile away from the road, then you set your units to .25 miles